# React native null is not an object (evaluating '_scrollView.scrollTo') on Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

React native null is not an object (evaluating '_scrollView.scrollTo')  on Android

```
  componentDidMount() {

      let scrollValue = 0;
      setInterval(function(){
          scrollValue = scrollValue + width;   // width = screen width
          _scrollView.scrollTo({x: scrollValue})
      }, 3000);
}


<ScrollView
ref={(scrollView) => { _scrollView = scrollView; }}
horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true} >
 {items}
</ScrollView>
```

it's work auto slide content but when I'm going back from another page it's return error null is not an object (evaluating '_scrollView.scrollTo')  I don't know about that

Answer (score 2):

you have to check if _scrollView not null

```
if(this._scrollView != null){
 scrollValue = scrollValue + width;
 this._scrollView.scrollTo({x: scrollValue})
}

render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollView => this._scrollView = scrollView}
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
    >
      {items}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

I hope it will work as I resolved my issue like that way..

Answer (score 0):

You should save the reference on `this`. Even so it might work if the reference is in some other scope you will run into problems when multiple ScrollViews are mounted.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let scrollValue = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
      scrollValue = scrollValue + width;
      this._scrollView.scrollTo({x: scrollValue})
  }, 3000);
}

render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollView => this._scrollView = scrollView}
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
    >
      {items}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Be aware that `this` has to be binded by your-self when you create custom methods in your component

```
scrollListToLeft = () => {
  this._scrollView.scrollTo({x: 0})
}
```

Comment: I think this line here `setInterval(function() {` should be an arrow function like this 
`setInterval(() => {` so you can use `this` inside. otherwise you'll have to assign `this` to a variable.

Comment: Obviously. I even wrote a hint about that and missed the interval... Thanks! Changed it.

Comment: null is not an object (evaluating '_this6._scrollView.scrollTo')